# Do /cat/proc/partitions in 'cygwin' directly correspond to specific wmic entries?

Tags: powershell, cygwin, drive

Here's the output from cygwin

```
> cat /proc/partitions
    8     0 500107608 sda
    8     1    266240 sda1
    8     2     16384 sda2
    8     3 472585216 sda3   C:\
    8     4  26214400 sda4   D:\
    8     5   1024000 sda5
```

Here's the output from wmic in Powershell

```
> wmic diskdrive get Name,Model,SerialNumber,Size,Status

Model                  Name                SerialNumber          Size          Status
NVMe SAMSUNG MZVLW512  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  0025_38BB_1410_1481.  512105932800  OK
```

**Is 'sda' in cat/proc/partitions a 1:1 equivalence with '\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0'**

Followup - here I only have 1 disk drive. If I had multiple drives attached would there be an easy command to tell which 'wmic' entry corresponds to which 'proc/partitions' entry?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the sequence maintained. On my system the

```
SDA is PhysicalDrive0
SDB is PhysicalDrive1
```

and the dimensions in byte vs KB is almost matching

```
wmic diskdrive get Name,Model,SerialNumber,Size,Status
Model                       Name                SerialNumber    Size           Status
ST1000LM035-1RK172          \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  WL10S143        1000202273280  OK
SAMSUNG MZNLN256HAJQ-000H1  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  S3T6NE0JC13444  256052966400   OK

$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts

    8     0 976762584 sda
    8     1 960658432 sda1   D:\
    8     2  16102400 sda2   E:\
    8    16 250059096 sdb
    8    17    266240 sdb1
    8    18     16384 sdb2
    8    19 248765440 sdb3   C:\
    8    20   1003520 sdb4
```